# Nested, Remote, Round-Robin Pool in Akka.NET

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

I have started working with Akka.NET and was able an application with did self deployment on a remote system with multiple instances (deployment using a round-robin pool router with 5 instances).  However, now I want to be able to link multiple servers together.  Currently I have this working:

```
Local Actor --> Remote Actor --> 5 instances
```

However I am trying to do something like this:

```
           /--->Remote Actor #1 (server1.domain.com) --> 5 instances
Main Actor< --->Remote Actor #2 (server2.domain.com) --> 5 instances
           \--->Remote Actor #3 (server3.domain.com) --> 5 instances
```

When `Main Actor` has a message that needs to be processed, it sends it to `Remote Actor 1`, `2`, **OR** `3` in a round-robin fashion.  The remote actor who receives the message then sends it to one of the instances, also in a round-robin fashion.

From what I've read, it *seems* like I need to implement clustering.  However, I could not tell from the documentation I found about how to implement it with this kind of nested round-robin processing.  It sounded more like a decentralized network where a message from `Main Actor` would be passed to `Remote Actor 1`, `2`, **AND** `3` which is definitely not what I would like.

Is there any way with the standard Akka.NET NuGets to implement this or do I need to implement the my own round-robin code in `Main Actor` to send a message to each of the `Remote Actor`'s individual and then let them do their own, standard round-robin.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated as I am relatively new to using this library.  Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to create your own round-robin code. You are almost there, you just need a little tweaking of your code.

Have you gone through [this](https://getakka.net/articles/remoting/deployment.html)? What you need is to configure the hostnames.

[I created this to better explain this to you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdF14.png)

1. From `Main Actor/Router` you can remotely deploy `routers`
2. You can go through these two pages ([Router with remote actors](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/2127) and [How to use HOCON to configure your routers](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/blob/master/src/Unit-3/lesson3/README.md)) for better understanding.

Please let me know if this is not clear to you!

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mestical's response is what you want, but just to clarify:

1. You can have the Main Actor use a `Group` round robin router to send messages to the remote actor's on your sub-domains;
2. Each of those remote actors can implement a local `Pool` round robin router to load-balance work locally between N identical actors.

`Group` routers use the `ActorPath` to message actors created by someone else, whereas `Pool` routers create the N identical child actors. The former is generally used for message distribution between `ActorSystem`s over Akka.Cluster / Akka.Remote whereas the latter is primarily used to parallelize work.

What Akka.Cluster makes easier in your situation is the possibility for your `Group` router to dynamically discover new nodes at run-time (or old nodes removed when they're terminated,) whereas Akka.Remote requires that information to be baked into configuration at startup. Akka.Cluster is just more dynamic, in other words.